# Woocommerce shop side bar goes to the bottom on mobile view

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

This is my URL: http://www.aiowebdev.com/vapestation/

In the shop page on mobile view, my sidebar is at the bottom. I want it to be at the top, I tried using some CSS to make it go to the top but im using the divi theme. I dont know if that has something to do with it but Im not sure on how to make it go to the top.

If you need anymore details please let me know, been working on this for couple days now I cant seem to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a java script solution to this issue.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('body.woocommerce-page #sidebar').insertBefore( jQuery('body.woocommerce-page #left-area') );
})
```

Add this piece of javascript to your divi themes option.

[image]